# PyTorch Boolean - Stop Backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

I need to create a Neural Network where I use binary gates to zero-out certain tensors, which are the output of disabled circuits.

To improve runtime speed, I was looking forward to use `torch.bool` binary gates to stop backpropagation along disabled circuits in the network. However, I created a small experiment using the official `PyTorch` example for the CIFAR-10 dataset, and the runtime speed is exactly the same for any values for `gate_A` and `gate_B`: (this means that the idea is not working)

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv1a = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.conv2a = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.conv1b = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.conv2b = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # Only one gate is supposed to be enabled at random
        # However, for the experiment, I fixed the values to [1,0] and [1,1]
        choice  =  randint(0,1)
        gate_A  =  torch.tensor(choice   ,dtype = torch.bool) 
        gate_B  =  torch.tensor(1-choice ,dtype = torch.bool) 
        
        a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1a(x)))
        a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2a(a)))
        
        b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1b(x)))
        b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2b(b)))
        
        a *= gate_A
        b *= gate_B
        x  = torch.cat( [a,b], dim = 1 )
        
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

How can i define `gate_A` and `gate_B` in such a way that backpropagation effectively stops if they are zero?

PS. Changing `concatenation` dynamically at runtime would also change which weights are assigned to every module. (for example, the weights associated to `a` could be assigned to `b` in another pass, disrupting how the network operates).

Comment: Is `a` always meant to be enabled and `b` always meant to be disabled, like in your example? If not, which part of the code determines this?

Comment: No, they are supposed to change at random actually :)

Comment: So, you have two gates, and at random, exactly one is enabled?

Comment: Yes, that it correct. This technique is essential for Neural Architecture Search. The running times can increase exponentially if backpropagation along disabled gates is not stopped somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`torch.no_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html) (the code below can probably be made more concise):

```
def forward(self, x):
        # Only one gate is supposed to be enabled at random
        # However, for the experiment, I fixed the values to [1,0] and [1,1]
        choice  =  randint(0,1)
        gate_A  =  torch.tensor(choice   ,dtype = torch.bool) 
        gate_B  =  torch.tensor(1-choice ,dtype = torch.bool) 
        
        if choice:
            a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1a(x)))
            a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2a(a)))
            a *= gate_A
            
            with torch.no_grad(): # disable gradient computation
                b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1b(x)))
                b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2b(b)))
                b *= gate_B
        else:
            with torch.no_grad(): # disable gradient computation
                a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1a(x)))
                a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2a(a)))
                a *= gate_A
            
            b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1b(x)))
            b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2b(b)))
            b *= gate_B

        x  = torch.cat( [a,b], dim = 1 )
        
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

---

On a second look, I think the following is a simpler solution to the specific problem:

```
def forward(self, x):
        # Only one gate is supposed to be enabled at random
        # However, for the experiment, I fixed the values to [1,0] and [1,1]
        choice  =  randint(0,1)

        if choice:
            a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1a(x)))
            a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2a(a)))
            b = torch.zeros(shape_of_conv_output) # replace shape of conv output here
        else:
            b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1b(x)))
            b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2b(b)))
            a = torch.zeros(shape_of_conv_output) # replace shape of conv output here
       
        x  = torch.cat( [a,b], dim = 1 )
        
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Comment: @C-3PO On a second look, I am not sure that even this is necessary in your specific case. Why can't you just skip the forward pass computations as well for the disabled gate? Conditioned on choice, you could forward pass one half, concat the other half with zeroes, and proceed as before. (I think you can, but I am asking because of your PS in the question).

Comment: Yeah, I'm also thinking the same. I actually invented the code in the post below when I was having a coffee. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @C-3PO Nice, both turned out identical :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution, simply define a tensor with zeros when `a` or `b` are disabled :)

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv1a = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.conv2a = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.conv1b = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.conv2b = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        
        if randint(0,1):
            a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1a(x)))
            a = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2a(a)))
            b = torch.zeros_like(a)
        else:
            b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1b(x)))
            b = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2b(b)))
            a = torch.zeros_like(b)
        
        x  = torch.cat( [a,b], dim = 1 )
        
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

PS. I thought about this while I was having a coffee.